# Raspberry Pi Pico with PN532 reading cards with the use of interrupt

Tags: pi-pico, interrupts, micropython, nfc

The setup is as follows:

1. Raspberry Pi Pico
2. PN532 connected via SPI with pico. Pin IRQ on the PN532 is connected to GPIO20 on the pico
3. Micro python
4. Micro python PN532 NFC/RFID control library (SPI) https://github.com/Carglglz/NFC_PN532_SPI

I have modified the lib code below in order to use IRQ (irq was originally = None):

```
class PN532:
    """Driver for the PN532 connected over SPI. Pass in a hardware or bitbang
    SPI device & chip select digitalInOut pin. Optional IRQ pin (not used),
    reset pin and debugging output."""

    def __init__(self, spi, cs_pin, irq_pin, reset=None, debug=False):
        """Create an instance of the PN532 class using SPI"""
        self.debug = debug
        self._irq = irq_pin
        self.CSB = cs_pin
        self._spi = spi
        self.CSB.on()
        if reset:
            if debug:
                print("Resetting")
            _reset(reset)

        try:
            self._wakeup()
            # self.get_firmware_version()  # first time often fails, try 2ce
            return
        except (BusyError, RuntimeError):
            pass
        # self.get_firmware_version()
```

By the use of the following example code I am able to read cards:

```
# NFC_PN532.py tested
import NFC_PN532 as nfc
from machine import Pin, SPI, Timer
import time

global card_read
card_read = False

# Register a new hardware timer.
timer = Timer(-1)

# SPI
spi_dev = SPI(0, baudrate=400000)
cs = Pin(17, Pin.OUT)
cs.on()


# SENSOR INIT
irq_pin = Pin(20, Pin.IN)
irq_pin.on()
pn532 = nfc.PN532(spi_dev,cs,irq_pin)
ic, ver, rev, support = pn532.get_firmware_version()
print('Found PN532 with firmware version: {0}.{1}'.format(ver, rev))

# Configure PN532 to communicate with MiFare cards
pn532.SAM_configuration()

# FUNCTION TO READ 
def read_nfc(dev, tmot):
    """Accepts a device and a timeout in millisecs """
    #print('Reading...')
    uid = dev.read_passive_target(timeout=tmot)
    if uid is None:
        print("when uid none",irq_pin.value())
        card_read = False
    else:
        numbers = [i for i in uid]
        string_ID = '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(*numbers)
        print('Found card with UID:', [hex(i) for i in uid])
        print('Number_id: {}'.format(string_ID))
        card_read = True
        print("when uid something",irq_pin.value())

while True:
    read_nfc(pn532, 500)
    if card_read == True:
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

but IRQ pin doesn't change state:

```
...
when uid none 1
when uid none 1
when uid none 1
Found card with UID: ['0x35', '0xef', '0xb5', '0x36']
Number_id: 53-239-181-54
when uid something 1
...
```

I also googled for interrupted examples but I couldn't find something. I guess the next thing is to code for interrupts inside the Micro python but since the GPIO20 doesn't change state I can't test it yet.
So how do I utilize the IRQ function on the PN532?